# alternatives to rsync?

Tags: backup, wget, rsync

I'm trying to script a backup system for several servers, some Windows, some Linux. I'd love to be able to use rsync but I can't (at least not in all situations, since some servers I can't install rsync to, and some are Win servers).

I've tested with wget in FTP mode with the "timestamping" option, and it seems to work pretty well regardless of platform. Are there other options that may be more robust/reliable, that will do incremental backups regardless of platform?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to have a look at [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/). And Server Fault. ;)

Comment: thanks scytale-- that looks very promising! I considered posting on server fault but thought that this was on the edge of programming and servers-- maybe I'll cross post! thanks again

Answer (score 8):

You might try Unison.
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/